# sudo update-grub not working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows

I recently installed Ubuntu on a Windows 10 computer to implement a dual boot, but since I initially had some problems during the installation process I made some mess with the partitions.

Anyway, now Ubuntu starts up properly but I don't get a grub screen to choose which OS to use (in other words, I'm locked out from Windows).

Searching in some tutorials, I tried to write `sudo update-grub` and I get these errors:

```
error: invalid volume.
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1.  Check your device.map.
```

Nothing which references to Windows.

Furthermore, sdb1 is my hdd (with no operating systems), while windows is installed on sda2 (see below)

On the other hand, I can still see Windows partition on `sudo fdisk -l` or under `Other Locations > SSD`.

Any suggestions?

---

UPDATE:

This is my partition:

```
Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  577MB  576MB   primary   ntfs
 2      577MB   167GB  166GB   primary   ntfs
 3      167GB   168GB  1024MB  primary   fat32           boot, esp
 4      168GB   254GB  86,0GB  extended
 5      168GB   174GB  5999MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 6      174GB   254GB  80,0GB  logical   ext4
```

[List configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBULD.jpg)
[General Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igUsp.jpg)
[Appearence Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg8Sy.jpg)

I also tried to add

```
menuentry "Windows 10 (loader)"{
    insmod part_gpt
    search --set=root --file /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi --fs-uuid DA02-12A2
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

[see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453124/add-windows-10-to-grub2-bootloader), but I get `Error: invalid EFI file path` on boot (`/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` does not actually exist).

---

UPDATE 2:

sudo fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 93,94 MiB, 98484224 bytes, 192352 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 9,7 MiB, 9510912 bytes, 18576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 54,97 MiB, 57614336 bytes, 112528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 242,43 MiB, 254193664 bytes, 496472 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 54,97 MiB, 57618432 bytes, 112536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 240,82 MiB, 252493824 bytes, 493152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 160,16 MiB, 167931904 bytes, 327992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 49,8 MiB, 52203520 bytes, 101960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 238,49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: ADATA SU800     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0a7e098f

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048   1126399   1124352  549M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1126400 326035455 324909056  155G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3  *    326035456 328036351   2000896  977M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda4       328038398 496005119 167966722 80,1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       328038400 339755007  11716608  5,6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       339757056 496005119 156248064 74,5G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdb: 931,53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10EZEX-60W
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9dba35c9

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1          63 1953523119 1953523057 931,5G 42 SFS

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.




Disk /dev/loop8: 62,9 MiB, 65105920 bytes, 127160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 27,9 MiB, 28405760 bytes, 55480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Have you tried to use grub custermizer?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha I can't find Windows under "predefined"

Comment: Did you check whether you have windows boot manager check box checked in UEFI firmware settings? Also add the result of sudo fdisk -l and Gparted software.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha see my updated question for `sudo fdisk -l`. Where can I find that "Gparted software"? Inside UEFI firmware settings there's not windows boot manager (at at least it is not called like that)

Comment: Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt partitioned drives. You have MBR(msdos) since you have an extended partition, so Windows is BIOS boot. And then you cannot have Ubuntu in UEFI boot as Windows must have boot flag on its bootable partition. UEFI has to have boot flag on its ESP and only one boot flag per drive. Or you cannot mix UEFI & BIOS on same drive. Move boot flag back to Windows boot partition (with bootmgr & BCD) and confirm Windows boots, make sure fast start up is off. Use Boot-Repair to reinstall grub in BIOS mode. Since UEFI hardware better to have Windows in UEFI boot mode.

Comment: What @oldfred said is true. Try following his instructions. Gparted is a must have software. You can get in from Ubuntu software too.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha & oldfred I made some mess following these instruction and I had to format Ubuntu partition. At the moment I'm in from the USB installer. Is there a way to configure Windows and Ubuntu to have both BIOS or UEFI boot from the "Something else" section? Which partitions should I add?

Comment: @oldfred I can't tag two persons in the same comment. See above

Comment: Cannot have BIOS & UEFI on same drive. If multiple drives you can have Windows in now 35 yr old BIOS/MBR configuration. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt since 2012 & release of Windows 8. Backwards compatibility to BIOS/MBR was for large corporations who wanted same configuration across different hardware. If you must have Windows in BIOS mode, the Ubuntu must be BIOS if on same drive. A few have used an external SSD for Ubuntu and that works well and can be either UEFI or BIOS as you have to select from UEFI/BIOS boot menu to boot it.

Comment: That's ok for me having the same configuration for both OS. So I should: 1- Reinstall Ubuntu "as is" from my pen drive (it is still on UEFI). 2- Install Gparted on Ubuntu. 3- Use Gparted to somehow move windows to UEFI configuration. Am I right or is there any missing piece?

Comment: @Foxel You can't use Gparted to move windows to UEFI. You will have to re-install. But, install Gparted anyway. It is useful. Read this too: https://www.tecmint.com/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fixing can't see grub menu problem

Recent versions of GRUB have the timeout hidden. You can hold down `left-shift` during boot to bring the message up or edit your `/boot/grub/grub.conf` and remove `hiddenmeu` and set the default to something like 10 seconds `timeout=10`

For grub2 edit the `/etc/default/grub` file and make the following changes:

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

NOTE: The `#` symbol will comment out the `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` and will enable the menu

After making the changes run `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes.

This is what `/etc/default/grub` look like to me:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update

# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="5"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="false"
export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-gray/black"
export GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="magenta/black"
```

You can also try to edit these values with GUI using ***"grub customizer"*** software that can be downloaded from the Ubuntu Software centre.

[image: Grub Customizer]

### Fixing can't see Windows Boot Manager in grub menu problem.

Also, It seems that you have installed Ubuntu in *UEFI* mode and Windows in *Legacy BIOS*. You have 2 options. Change Windows to *UEFI* or change Ubuntu to *Legacy BIOS*. It is recommended to change Windows to *UEFI* because *UEFI* is better and more advanced than *Legacy BIOS*.

**1) Change Windows to UEFI:**
You can do this by reinstalling Windows or you can try to do what is mentioned in [here](https://www.wintips.org/how-to-change-legacy-to-uefi-without-reinstall-windows-10/). **Whatever you do, make user that you have a backup, just in case.**

**2) Change Ubuntu to Legacy BIOS:**
You can do this by reinstalling Ubuntu but making sure that you don't pick the *UEFI* option in boot options. (The *UEFI* option will have "**UEFI:**" before the name of your installation media. Note that the names of *UEFI* option and *Legacy BIOS* option may differ. **For more info read the chat in comments.**

Comment: Will this also make the "invalid volume" error when running `sudo grub-update` go away ?

Comment: @SorenA Please try...

Comment: @SasukeUchiha I opened grub.cfg but there's not any hiddenmeu/hiddenmenu options. (only a bunch of functions in a never-seen language). Furthermore, on the very top of that script it says DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE (is it normal). How can I decect whether I'm using grab or grab 2? On /etc/default/grub there's not GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 (ONLY GRUB_TIMEOUT)

Comment: @Foxel What is the value if grub_timeout?

Comment: @Foxel If you are unsure about editing it download grub customizer and increase the timeout there. Also, you can change the position of boot options from it.

Comment: I've done it. Now the grub gets displayed, but no options for Windows (only Ubuntu - Ubuntu Advanced Feature - UEFI manager)

Comment: @Foxel As you recently installed Ubuntu you will have grub 2. Answer edited.

Comment: @Foxel Download Grub Customizer and post screenshots from List configuration, General settings and Appearance settings tabs.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha see my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107697/discussion-between-sasuke-uchiha-and-foxel).

Comment: @Foxel Did it work?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha it did! I was even able to create a shared NTFS partition, and now I'm trying new thing, hoping not to make further mess... Thank you again for your help

Comment: I still don't have enough reputation for an upvote

Comment: @Foxelf no prob